# How to give fadein effect to the flexslider content

Tags: javascript, flexslider

I am using the content slider from flex slider. From the below mentioned html code and javascript, the slider and the content works fine for me with slider slide animation effect.

But the content suddenly comes while sliding. I want a fadein effect for that content while sliding, so that my slider looks some what beautiful.

My html code is,

```
  <section class="slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
        <div class="image"><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg"/></a></div>
                <div class="data">
                    <h4>First Heading</h4>
                    <p>First Para</p>
                    <span>Read More</span>
                </div>
        </li>

         <li>
        <div class="image"><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg"/></a></div>
                <div class="data">
                    <h4>Second Heading</h4>
                    <p>Second Para</p>
                    <span>Read More</span>
                </div>
        </li>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

My javascript is,

```
(function($){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,


  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: animation: "fade" please try

Comment: i dont want the slider animation as fade. I want only the content should fade that is mentioned in the <div class="data">

Answer (score 2):

From the [Flexslider docs](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/):

```
before: function(){}, //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
```

```
slider.animatingTo //Int: Useful in .before(), the slide currently animating to
```

So you can do something like this:

```
// Have a variable for the animation speed,
// so we can keep our "slide" and "fade" syncronized.
var myAnimationSpeed = 600;

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  slideshowSpeed: 7000,
  animationSpeed : myAnimationSpeed,
  before : function(slider){
    $('ul.slides li:eq(' + slider.animatingTo + ') div.data') // Select the next slide
    .hide() // Hide it...
    .fadeIn(myAnimationSpeed); // ...and fade !
  }

});
```

Comment: while changing the animation speed, the slider only moves slowly.. The contents are not fading in or out..

Comment: Maybe `$('ul.slides li:eq(' + slider.animatingTo + ') div.data')` is not selecting the right element. Try just `$('div.data')` instead, to see if it actually does something.

Comment: working fine dude.. Thank you very much.. can you do another favor for me.. Fade in works fine. Like the same way could you please give a code for fade out also.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can validate my answer if it helped. I think the fade out shouldn't be too hard. This should work inside the same `before` callback: `$('ul.slides li:eq(' + slider.currentSlide + ') div.data').fadeOut(myAnimationSpeed);`

Comment: after using this fade out, my content disappears when clicking the next slide. Is there any possible way to add both fade in and fade out. because while moving to the next slide, the content suddenly goes out.. if it fades out means it look some what better..

Comment: You have to target the right elements for `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. Check out the Flexslider docs for the `before` callback and the `slider` object. You should probably sort this out by using the `slider.animatingTo` and `slider.currentSlide` indexes to target the right elements.